# NodeJS/express - get parameter from URL

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I am trying to get a parameter from my URL in node. 
I know how to do it for this type of parameter:

```
app.get('/item/:name', function(req,res){
   console.log(req.params.name);
}
```

But how do it get my tag parameter here:

```
app.get('/item/:name?tag=somevalue', function(req,res){
   console.log(req.params.name);
}
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As Ben points out in the comments, with express you can do:

```
req.query.tag
```

Without express, with [`url`](http://nodejs.org/api/url.html), something like:

```
var u = url.parse(req.url, true);
```

`u.query` contains the query string parameters, `u.query.tag` is the one you need.

Comment: You don't need to do all that with Express, you can just use `req.query`, so `req.query.tag`.